# Unable to build JMeter 3.3

Tags: jmeter, ant

Whenever I am trying to build Jmeter 3.3 source code I am getting the following

```
Buildfile: E:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.3_src\apache-jmeter-3.3\build.xml
_check_3rdparty:
_message_3rdParty:
     [echo] Cannot find all the required 3rd party libraries.
     [echo] If building from a release, you can get most of them from the binary archive.
     [echo] Use "ant download_jars" to download any missing jars.

BUILD FAILED
E:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.3_src\apache-jmeter-3.3\build.xml:1199: Cannot find required classes

Total time: 3 seconds
```

information the console I am using Eclipse IDE can anyone help with the steps on how to build an ant project and where should I use ant download_jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Executing Ant tasks from Eclipse](https://www.openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/ant-from-eclipse_en.html) you should be able to run `download_jars` task just like you're running `build` task.

If you need more detailed steps (however it shouldn't be the case for a person who wants to build JMeter from source)

1. From Eclipse main menu choose Window -> Show View -> Ant

   [image]
2. Click "Add Buildfiles"

   [image]
3. Locate `build.xml` in the root of JMeter sources downloaded folder
4. Now you have `download_jars` task

   [image]

   which can be run as ant build from context menu, it will retrieve all the dependencies and store them to "lib" folder

Just in case be informed that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter and JMeter 3.3 is kind of 5 years old so maybe considering migrating to [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) would be a better idea?